# Iphone can we mute Ear Speakers and only play from the Bottom Speakers?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, speaker

I need audio from a single iPhone speaker. Preferably just the bottom speaker. Currently I am getting audio from both the Ear and Bottom speakers.

I have tried every permutation of AVAudioSession category and port.
I get an OSStatus error -50 when I try to overrideOutputAudioPort to .speaker, and believe this is the root of my problem.

The override is failing on an iPhone X, iPhone XR and iPhone 6s+

Currently use this as setup:

try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker) // This fails OSStatus error -50

Answer (score -1):

"Solution" I found was to set pan

audioPlayer.pan = -1

Pan all to the left so that it uses the bottom speaker and not the Ear Speaker. So may not be a solution for everyone. Also note this pan to the -1 only works in portrait mode. It must be adjusted on orientation changes.

Also solution to the  OSStatus error -50 appears to be setting category to .playAndRecord. Then setting to .speakers works. However, this still plays out both speakers and was not the route problem for me.